# Fixed header Java Script not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I'm using a fixed header script which works fine in modern browsers but is not working at all in Internet Explorer 11. I can see that it doesn't add the fixed-classes in IE which are needed for CSS. Tried to debug it, but the console isn't showing anything to me.

Ì added a document.querySelector polyfill and started using window.pageYOffset instead of the original code. But still not working in IE11.

I am wondering if there's maybe a problem with the throtteling and fireing the event at scrolling (please take a look at the end of the script).

```
/* FIXEDTHINGs-SCRIPT 2019-09-27 13.13 */

//Fix document.querySelector for old browser
// https://gist.github.com/chrisjlee/8960575
if (!document.querySelector) {
  document.querySelector = function (selectors) {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(selectors);
    return (elements.length) ? elements[0] : null;
  };
}
// End Fix for old browser

// ############## Create variables for relevant wrappers ##############   
const stickyWrapper = document.querySelector(".sticky-wrapper");
const navWrapper = document.querySelector(".nav-wrapper");
const searchWrapper = document.querySelector(".search-wrapper");
const containerWrapper = document.querySelector(".container-wrapper");

// ############## GET HEIGHT ##############
// ... of stickyWrapper
let stickyWrapperHeight = stickyWrapper.getBoundingClientRect().height;

// ... of navWrapper 
let navWrapperHeight = navWrapper.getBoundingClientRect().height;

// ... of searchWrapper 
let searchWrapperHeight = searchWrapper.getBoundingClientRect().height;

// ############## GET TOP POSITION ##############
// ... of navWrapper 
let navWrapperTop = navWrapper.getBoundingClientRect().top;

// ... of searchWrapper 
let searchWrapperTop = searchWrapper.getBoundingClientRect().top;

// ############## GET ORIGINAL POSITION ##############
// ... of stickyWrapper
// 1. take top position of stickyWrapper   
// 2. take away the height of stickyWrapper
// 3. add the number of pixels the doc has currently scrolled
let stickyWrapperOrigPos = stickyWrapper.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - stickyWrapperHeight + window.pageYOffset;   

// ... of searchWrapper
// 1. take bottom position of StickyWrapper 
// 2. take away the height of searchWrapper
// 3. add the number of pixels the doc has currently scrolled
let searchWrapperOrigPos = stickyWrapper.getBoundingClientRect().bottom - searchWrapperHeight + window.pageYOffset;   

// ... of navWrapper
// 1. take bottom position of StickyWrapper 
// 2. take away the height of searchWrapper  
// 3. take away the height of navWrapper
// 4. add the number of pixels the doc has currently scrolled
let navWrapperOrigPos = stickyWrapper.getBoundingClientRect().top - searchWrapperHeight - navWrapperHeight + window.pageYOffset;   

// ############## GET ORIGINAL TOP POSITION ##############
// ... of stickyWrapper
// 1. take top position of stickyWrapper   
let stickyWrapperOrigPosTop = stickyWrapper.getBoundingClientRect().top;   

// ############## GET ORIGINAL BOTTOM POSITION ##############
// ... of stickyWrapper
// 1. take bottom position of stickyWrapper   
let stickyWrapperOrigPosBot = stickyWrapper.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;   


// ############## START AND STOP FIXED-EFFECT AT THE RIGHT MOMENT ##############
function stickyThingInit() {
  // check top-Position again (f.e. user refreshes page)
  navWrapperTop = navWrapper.getBoundingClientRect().top;  
  searchWrapperTop = searchWrapper.getBoundingClientRect().top; 
  searchWrapperHeight = searchWrapper.getBoundingClientRect().height; 

  // if window's scroll Y position is at searchWrapper top position
  if (window.pageYOffset > searchWrapperOrigPos) {   

      // add the fixed class to the stickyWrapper
      stickyWrapper.classList.add("sticky-wrapper-fixed");

      // add the fixed class to the searchWrapper
      searchWrapper.classList.add("search-wrapper-fixed");

      // add the fixed class to the navWrapper
      navWrapper.classList.add("nav-wrapper-fixed"); 

      // add the height of searchWrapper to the nav wrapper as top so that it shows after the new searchWrapper position
      navWrapper.style.top = searchWrapperHeight + "px";

      //add padding top to the containerWrapper to prevent jumping and make content visible
      containerWrapper.style.paddingTop = (searchWrapperHeight + navWrapperHeight) + "px";          
  }     

  // If the window's scroll Y position and the height of the searchWrapper and the height of the navWrapper are less than the stickyWrapper top position
  if (window.pageYOffset <= stickyWrapperOrigPosTop) {  

      // remove the sticky class from stickyWrapper
      stickyWrapper.classList.remove("sticky-wrapper-fixed"); 

      // remove the sticky class from searchWrapper
      searchWrapper.classList.remove("search-wrapper-fixed");  

      // remove the sticky class from navWrapper
      navWrapper.classList.remove("nav-wrapper-fixed");  

      // remove the height inline-style from navWrapper
      navWrapper.removeAttribute("style");

      // remove the height inline-style from containerWrapper
      containerWrapper.removeAttribute("style");
  }
}


// function that throttles the event listener (or any function we add)
function throttled(delay, fn) {
  let lastCall = 0;
  return function (...args) {
    const now = (new Date).getTime();
    if (now - lastCall < delay) {
      return;
    }
    lastCall = now;
    return fn(...args);
  }
}

// On scroll, fire the function
throttled(400, window.addEventListener("scroll", stickyThingInit));
```

Any idea why it is not working?

Comment: This looks complicated for a fixed header, have you considered position: sticky and just letting the 3 IE11 users in the world not having a sticky header?

Comment: I suggest you to post your whole code whch includes HTML, CSS and JS which can reproduce the issue with IE 11. With above code we are not able to test the issue on our side. Also please try to inform us what exactly is not working. From the comment, it looks like you posted your development requirement. We can only provide suggestions for your issue related with IE. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $("#bar").mmenu({
       "slidingSubmenus": false,
       "extensions": [
         "fx-menu-zoom",
         "fx-panels-zoom",
         "pagedim-black",
         "theme-dark",
         "border-offset"
       ],
       "navbars": [{
         "position": "top",
         "content": [
           "<a class='fa fa-user' target='_blank' href='https://facebook.com/mwemaco'></a>",
           "<a class='fa fa-history' target='_blank' href='https://twitter.com/mwemaco'></a>",
           "<a class='fa fa-envelope' target='_blank' href='https://youtube.com/mwemaco'></a>",
           "<a class='fa fa-envelope' target='_blank' href='https://youtube.com/mwemaco'></a>"
         ]
       }, {
         "position": "bottom",
         "content": [
           "<a class='fa fa-facebook' target='_blank' href='https://facebook.com/mwemaco'></a>",
           "<a class='fa fa-twitter' target='_blank' href='https://twitter.com/mwemaco'></a>",
           "<a class='fa fa-youtube' target='_blank' href='https://youtube.com/mwemaco'></a>",
           "<a class='fa fa-instagram' target='_blank' href='https://instagram.com/mwemaco'></a>"
         ]
       }]
     }, {
       classNames: {
         fixedElements: {
           fixed: "hdr-fixer"
         }
       },
       offCanvas: {
         pageSelector: "#page"
       },
     });
     var API = $("#bar").data("mmenu");
     $("#bar").click(function() {
       API.open();
     });
   });

</script>
<style type="text/css">
  .page {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: bock
}

.bar {
  display: block
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px #d9d9d9 solid;
}

.hdr-fixer {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 7;
}

#bar:not(.mm-menu) {
  display: none;
}

.content {
  display: block
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page" class="page">
  <div class="header hdr-fixer">
    <a href="#bar">MENU</a>
  </div>
  <div id="bar" class="bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">App</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/about/history">History</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about/team">The team</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about/address">Our address</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Hello
    <br>
    <br>Hello
    <br>
    <br>Hello
    <br>
    <br>Hello
    <br>
    <br>Hello
    <br>
    <br>Hello
    <br>
    <br>Hello
    <br>
    <br>Hello
    <br>
    <br>Hello
    <br>
    <br>Hello
    <br>
    <br>Hello
    <br>
    <br>Hello
    <br>
    <br>Hello
    <br>
    <br>Hello
    <br>
    <br>Hello
    <br>
    <br>Hello
    <br>
    <br>Hello
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Please take a look at this function. 
Fixed header is working fine at IE 11.

Comment: Thank your for answering! I fear though, that these are totally different scripts and quite some otherpreconditions in my situation, so that I can't compare them :)

I need some classes to be added to elements as soon as the user scrolls past an area, need to make sure that it gets removed as soon as the user scrolls above another area, need to throttle the whole thing and so on. I am also not only thinking about one area, but need to think about several areas :)

I am wondering, why IE11 is not adding the sticky-wrapper-fixed, search-wrapper-fixed and nav-wrapper-fixed classes. :)